# why is my object solve not matching my plane track?

Tags: tracking

Ok so im tracking a flat piece of paper and everything seems to look great! when i add a plane track to the points it follows the paper perfectly.  but for some reason when i use the object motion solve and set up the tracking scene the points don't follow the paper any more.  can anyone help me or explain what i'm doing wrong please?

Thanks in advance.

here is a screen shot of it.  left side shows the plane track around the paper and fitting it perfectly. on the right side it shows the plane up right and not tilting back like it should.

[image]

Comment: The "plane track" can be used in the compositor to place an image over the page you tracked. To have an object follow the markers you need to go to reconstruction and set floor etc while object is selected in 3dview.

Comment: @sambler Care to make that an answer with some more details?

Answer (score 1):

Tracking a piece of paper as it moves around in a video is a matter of following some points on the video, an image can then be distorted relatively easy to match the movement of the plane.

To track camera movement you need points that are not only following points on the video but that can also be used to define a three dimensional box in front of the camera. When reconstructing camera motion you specify some points that are flat on the ground and also raised up on a wall. This provides a way to re-create the camera movement relative to the given points.

Once you have the camera movement you can then track objects that move relative to these points.

With enough points on an object you can get the same effect as an object moving in front of the camera, but in your example video you have nothing that adds height to the sheet so there is no way of re-creating the rotation of the page, the best you can do is distort a 2d image to match the distortion of the page in front of the camera.

In your screenshot you have a solve error of 18.65. A solve error less than 1.0 is considered a good track with values up to 3.0 considered possibly good enough to work with. Anything higher than 3.0 is considered a bad track.